# XML Serialize List of generic objects derived from an interface,,,

Tags: c#, xml, generics, serialization, interface

So I'm trying to XML serialize a `List<IObject>` derrived from an interface, but the `IObjects` are generic types... best resort to code:

```
public interface IOSCMethod
{
    string Name { get; }
    object Value { get; set; }
    Type Type { get; }
}

public class OSCMethod<T> : IOSCMethod
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get { return _type; } }

    protected string _name;
    protected Type _type;

    public OSCMethod() { }

    // Explicit implementation of IFormField.Value
    object IOSCMethod.Value
    {
        get { return this.Value; }
        set { this.Value = (T)value; }
    }
}
```

And I have a List of IOSCMethods:

```
List<IOSCMethod>
```

of which I add objects to in the following way:

```
        List<IOSCMethod> methodList = new List<IOSCMethod>();
        methodList.Add(new OSCMethod<float>() { Name = "/1/button1", Value = 0 });
        methodList.Add(new OSCMethod<float[]>() { Name = "/1/array1", Value = new float[10] });
```

And it's this **`methodList`** which is what I'm trying to serialize. But everytime I try, either I get a "Can't serialize an interface" but when I make it (either the `IOSCMethod` or the `OSCMethod<T>` class) implement `IXmlSerializable` I get the problem of "can't serialize an object with a parameterless constructor. but obviously I can't because it's an interface! lame pants.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What serializer  are you using?  Post the code for that?

Comment: My guess is the reason this complains is because there's no way to deserialize to an interface afterwards. The .NET XML serialisation mechanism probably assumes that a type serializes-then-deserializes to its original type, which means that any type you're serializing from must be possible to deserialize to.

Comment: XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(methodList.GetType());

Comment: And yes... more than likely. I want out of it the same as what I put into it, a List<IOSCMethod> but essentially a list of different typed OSCMethod<T> (i.e. OSCMethod<float>, OSCMethod<float[,]> etc etc...)

Comment: Take a look at the XmlArrayItem attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SerializeOscTest
{
    [Test]
    public void SerializeEmpTest()
    {
        var oscMethods = new List<OscMethod>
                             {
                                  new OscMethod<float> {Value = 0f}, 
                                  new OscMethod<float[]> {Value = new float[] {10,0}}
                              };
        string xmlString = oscMethods.GetXmlString();
    }
}

public class OscMethod<T> : OscMethod
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(OscMethod<float>)),XmlInclude(typeof(OscMethod<float[]>))]
public abstract class OscMethod
{

}

public static class Extenstion
{
    public static string GetXmlString<T>(this T objectToSerialize)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string xml;
        using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(stringBuilder)))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, objectToSerialize);
            xml = stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
        return xml;
    }
}
```